# How to remove dotnet projects from a solution without removing the project-to-project references (with Visual Studio)

Tags: .net, reference

Is it possible to remove a project from a solution but keep the project-to-project references inside the .csproj file?
Currently we work on a codebase consisting of many projects, each referencing other projects via assembly references. Everyone in my team has their own user solutions with only subsets of all the projects in them. I thought project-to-project references could be a better way to go, but during my tests I could not remove a project from a user solution without also removing the project-to-project references to that project from all the other project files in that solution. If we cannot freely remove projects in our own user solutions without breaking the dependencies in our product solution we have to stick to the assembly references (with all their drawbacks).
Am I missing something here (some settings I need to change) or is there another way of removing projects from a solution?

Update:
What I try to figure out is whether project-to-project refs are better for us than assembly refs (with their benefits like dependency resolution).

Update 2:
I read [Architecture of a .NET Application: Case Studies](https://blog.ndepend.com/architecture-of-a-net-application-case-studies/) which also states, that assembly refs are indeed needed for multiple solutions. Maybe I have to come up with another approach to optimize our workflow.

Thank you Luis for your comments!

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible, but why would you need that? I read your question twice and couldn't understand what you're trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: The current workflow consists of many people working with their own small solutions with only a few projects in them. There is one main sln that holds all projects. The projects reference each other using assembly refs (what I thought could be improved by using project-to-project refs). To see if p2p refs really make things better, I converted every ref in the main sln to p-2-p and used some of those projects in my own sln. Then I removed one project from my sln and VS automatically removed the refs to this project from all the other projects in that sln thus breaking the refs in the main sln.

Comment: Yes, I agree, VS does that automatically. That's because it's not really counting on that 'micro SLN' + 'macro SLN' structure. I have now a clear picture of what you're doing, but still not a clear understanding on why you do it. Which purpose does that structure serve?

Comment: Well, my team works like this. Personally, I would go for one sln with p2p refs and let everyone work with it but that's not how everyone else is used to work. I don't think I can convince my colleagues to change their habits (regarding the user slns), so I thought maybe use p2p refs and keep those user slns. I really want to get rid of 3rd party tools for dependency resolution or buildorder settings (what from my understanding would be obsolete if we use p2p refs).